# KafkaStreams: Unexpected state transition from NOT_RUNNING to REBALANCING

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am getting error as "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected state transition from NOT_RUNNING to REBALANCING" while starting the KafkaStreams.

Kafka version: 2.3.1
Scala 2.12

As part of stream processing, created two GlobalKTable and have join with KStream.
The above error is when started the stream, below is the error stack

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream-client web-click-charts-1cdb2c98-079e-4228-bbe6-df14d18b1e99: Unexpected state transition from NOT_RUNNING to REBALANCING
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.setState(KafkaStreams.java:261)
>           at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.start(KafkaStreams.java:787)
>           at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa.bbb.StreamProcessInitiator.main(StreamProcessInitiator.java:36)

I deployed the process using 'kafka-run-class'

Comment: Sound like a bug. Can you please file a bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA

Comment: The issue got resolved. Issue was before starting the stream, I was doing close(). By commenting the close() method it is working. Thanks